# umbraco 4.7.1.1 can't upload new image in insert image dialog

Tags: umbraco

I recently migrated from umbraco 4.0.4.2 to 4.7.1.1

in the old umbraco the insert image dialog included the media tree & a create new tab
[image: In umbraco 4.0.4.2]

and the new one doesn't..
[image: In umbraco 4.7.1.1]

we need to be able to upload pictures directly from the editor.
how do I do this?

thanks!
Igal

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco v4.7 insert image does work as you have previously experienced for a clean install. However for some reason this does occur when upgrading from older umbraco versions.

I would suggest updating Tiny MCE: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/24523-Why-not-update-jquery-and-tinymce-to-latest-version